# why my html page is not getting render in <ui-view>?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to wireup angularjs with rails. I am having some issues with my views. They are not getting render in

My view is getting fetched but with an error [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]

I am getting this in response of first.html
https://github.com/sourabh-garg/vegeta/blob/master/response%20error.html

In app/assets/templates/first.html that I am trying to load.

app/views/application/index.html.erb has my index file

**Route** root 'application#index'

**App.js**

```
   var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router'])

      .config(function config($stateProvider){

       $stateProvider.state("index", {
        url : "",
        controller : "FirstCtrl as first",
        templateUrl : "first.html"
       })

       $stateProvider.state("second", {
        url : "/second",
        controller : "SecondCtrl as second",
        templateUrl : "second.html"
       })

      })
      .directive('elem', function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: "templates/second.html"
        };
      })
      .filter('reverse', function(){

      return function(text){
        return text.split('').reverse().join('');
      }

      })
      .service("greeting", function Greeting(){

        var greeting =  this;

        greeting.message =  "Default";
       })
      .service('Data', [function () {

        return {message: "You are a awesome"}
      }])
      .controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, greeting, Data){

        var first = this;
        first.greeting = greeting;

        first.data = Data;

        first.reversed = function(message){
          return message.split('').reverse().join('');

        };

      })
      .controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, greeting){

        var second = this;
        second.greeting = greeting;
      });
```

Comment: is "/second" showing up and working?

Comment: No it's not. I see one mistake "templates/first.html" it should be only "first.html". Even after correcting it. It's not working.

Comment: Are you sure `templateUrl: "templates/second.html"` is pointing to the correct location?  It's not `templateUrl: "/app/assets/templates/second.html"`?

Comment: acutally it's only "first.html" or "second.html" as I am using rails-angular-template gem it automatically looks into the /app/assets/templates/

Answer (score 1):

1) You are using `gem angular-rails-templates`.

Don't you have to Inject the templates module into your Angular app?
`angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router', 'templates'])`

---

2) In your file structure `app/assets/javascripts/`, the `application.js` file on line 5, see if changing `//= require_tree .` to `//= require_tree ../templates` corrects the link.

**Resource:** [angular-rails-template: include templates in rails assets pipeline](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates#2-include-templates-in-rails-asset-pipeline)

Comment: This could be it. The error makes it seem like the page is being redirected to the Rails endpoint, which doesn't exist, instead of the Angular App's route endpoint.

Comment: Yes correct. But even after that it didn't work. I had to keep my html files in public folder then it worked only.

Answer (score 0):

Your config function is written inaccurately, try

`.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {`

The $stateProvider is used twice.
`// Now set up the states`

`// For any unmatched url, send to /route1
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/first");`

`$stateProvider
    .state('first', {
      url: "/first",
      templateUrl: "first.html"
    })
    .state('second', {
      url: "/second",
      templateUrl: "second.html"
    });
}])`

Comment: No that's not the issue. I have tried without naming the function also. But it didn't work.

Comment: Only my views are not getting render. If I use template instead of templateUrl then it's working fine. could be an issue with gem - rails-angular-template ?

Comment: Remove `$stateProvider` from `$stateProvider.state("second"`  

You already have `$stateProvider` initiated and the second state should be chaining.

Comment: did that. Still the same issue.

Comment: Lets try    
  
`.state('first', {
      url: "/first",
      templateUrl: "first.html"
    })`